# how can you draw an X(or some marker) on an imagebutton when clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, imagebutton

**I am using visual studio using asp.net and c#**

I currently have an imagebutton and when you click on the image it tells you the coordinates and adds them into a table. I now need to make it so when you click the image it also leaves a marker there such as an X. Im new to visual studio and the language so I am wondering what the best way to accomplish this.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "The shot is recorded at the coordinates: (" +
                   e.X.ToString() + ", " + e.Y.ToString() + ")";
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["xCoordinate"].DefaultValue = e.X.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["yCoordinate"].DefaultValue = e.Y.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

this is what I have for my event handler so far, im assuming i need to use some drawing function to leave the marker on the image but I don't know the code to do so.

I haven't found a question on here for what Im trying to do, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a desktop app or for a web page? How is this related to ASP.Net?

Comment: its a web page, sorry

Comment: @sevatitov: asp.net is web

Comment: Are you needing these markers to be persistent between page loads?

Comment: the markers are tracking shots on net in a game and there will be multiple games the markers need to be saved for

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to draw shapes based on data from the server. Drawing multiple points is left as an exercise to the reader but I imagine this should get you started.

Drawing is done client-side with an HTML `<canvas>` element. I have server-side aspx markup. Make sure to set the `ClientIDMode` to static.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="pentagon.jpg" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ImageButton1" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="HiddenShots" />
```

And the code-behind: (note this depends on Newtonsoft.Json)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// ... 

protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = $"The short is recorded at coordinates ({e.X}, {e.Y})";
    HiddenShots.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);
}
```

What this does is gets the state of the click back to the client side in a hidden field. Here, you would load the shots from your database and serialize a collection of them instead.

Finally, the client side script that draws on the canvas.

```
(function( imgButton, shots ) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        imgButtonRect = imgButton.getBoundingClientRect();

    canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
    canvas.style.top = imgButtonRect.top + 'px';
    canvas.style.left = imgButtonRect.left + 'px';
    canvas.width = imgButton.width;
    canvas.height = imgButton.height;
    canvas.style.zIndex = 1;
    canvas.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    imgButton.parentNode.appendChild(canvas);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(shots.X, shots.Y, 6, 6);
})(
    document.getElementById( "ImageButton1" ),
    JSON.parse( document.getElementById("HiddenShots").value)
);
```

This creates a canvas and positions it directly over the `ImageButton`, then uses the data from the hidden field to draw the shot.